# sshfs - device not found

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, sshfs

After updating the server with `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` this command return an error

## OS

```
Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 x86_64 (wheezy)
```

## command

```
echo "the-password" | sshfs root@domain.com:/var/www /remote_mount -o password_stdin
```

## error

```
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

## update

```
root@dyntest-amd-3700-2gb ~ # modprobe fuse
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'fuse': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

.

```
root@dyntest-amd-3700-2gb ~ # dmesg | grep fuse
[   20.126156] fuse: Unknown symbol nosteal_pipe_buf_ops (err 0)
[1607702.343086] fuse: Unknown symbol nosteal_pipe_buf_ops (err 0)
[1607745.824310] fuse: Unknown symbol nosteal_pipe_buf_ops (err 0)
[1607908.188559] fuse: Unknown symbol nosteal_pipe_buf_ops (err 0)
[1608724.690945] fuse: Unknown symbol nosteal_pipe_buf_ops (err 0)
[1608741.684927] fuse: Unknown symbol nosteal_pipe_buf_ops (err 0)
[2565283.964259] fuse: Unknown symbol nosteal_pipe_buf_ops (err 0)
```

Kernel version

```
root@dyntest-amd-3700-2gb ~ # cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2

root@dyntest-amd-3700-2gb ~ # locate -i -r /fuse
/bin/fuser
/bin/fusermount
/etc/fuse.conf
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/fuse
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/fuse/cuse.ko
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/fuse/fuse.ko
/lib/modules-load.d/fuse.conf
/usr/include/boost/fusion/functional/adapter/fused.hpp
/usr/include/boost/fusion/functional/adapter/fused_function_object.hpp
/usr/include/boost/fusion/functional/adapter/fused_procedure.hpp
/usr/include/boost/fusion/include/fused.hpp
/usr/include/boost/fusion/include/fused_function_object.hpp
/usr/include/boost/fusion/include/fused_procedure.hpp
/usr/include/linux/fuse.h
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/fusermount
/usr/share/doc/fuse
/usr/share/doc/fuse/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/fuse/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/fuse/copyright
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fuse
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/fuse
/usr/share/man/man1/fuser.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/fusermount.1.gz
/var/cache/apt/archives/fuse_2.9.0-2+deb7u1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/fuse_2.9.3-14_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/fuse_2.9.3-15_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/fuse_2.9.3-9_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.preinst
```

## update #2

```
root@dyntest-amd-3700-2gb /var/www # modinfo fuse
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/fuse/fuse.ko
alias:          devname:fuse
alias:          char-major-10-229
license:        GPL
description:    Filesystem in Userspace
author:         Miklos Szeredi <miklos@szeredi.hu>
depends:
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.2.0-4-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           max_user_bgreq:Global limit for the maximum number of backgrounded requests an unprivileged user can set (uint)
parm:           max_user_congthresh:Global limit for the maximum congestion threshold an unprivileged user can set (uint)
```

Comment: May be a silly question but did you try `modprobe fuse` ?

Comment: This question should be in superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: How would you put `modprobe fuse` into the syntax with `sshfs`?

Comment: @clarkk: `modprobe fuse` will load the FUSE kernel module. It is supposed to be executed on system start-up or by a user with `root` privileges...

Comment: `modprobe fuse` returns an error.. have updated the question

Comment: Did you try to "see dmesg", as the error message suggests? (Run `dmesg | grep fuse` after trying to load the module)

Comment: Have you updated kernel as well? If yes, you may need to reboot.

Comment: Have just rebooted.. Still same error

Comment: Please, check for fuse in `/var/log/messages`, and update question with your kernel and fuse package versions. Maybe it's more easy that you imagine and you need only to [update the kernel and reboot](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=113906).

Comment: question updated with kernel versions.. looks like they are equal.. but don't know how to look for `fuse` errors

Comment: What does this have to do with programming? This belongs on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using (and version). Can you provide the info returned by `modinfo fuse`. And can you load up (in an editor) the file `/boot/grub/grub.conf` and tell me what appears on the end of the line after `set default=`. Often it will be "0" I am curious if yours is something different.

Comment: If you are on debian I also recommend doing this command: `dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64`  (if using (K)Ubuntu derivative then it would be `sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64`. After issuing that command reboot and try fuse again

Comment: have updated question with OS etc... After running `dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64` and reboot `fuse` still return errors

Comment: Did you try to uninstall (with purge option ) both kernel and fuse packages and after reinstall them? (Here again, broken HD...). Just a specification: the kernel version you provide is the one of the server?

Comment: No havent tried that.. Could you provide both uninstall and install commands? :)

Comment: Yes, this is kernel version of the server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This thread](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=113906) appears to have a solution - basically upgrade your kernel.

Btw. the reason for this according to an exchange between Luis Henriques and Al Viro on [LKML](https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/2/7/182) was an API rename in the kernel to merge a FUSE flag with another more general flag.

Comment: This is the absolutely correct answer, though it is a bit vague if you aren't experienced with kernel recompiling.  Not all Linux distributions come with the FUSE flag set by default in the kernel modules.  Debian and Gentoo are offenders here.  Updating the kernel flags to enable FUSE is a procedure that depends on which operating system you have.  When you recompile your kernel with FUSE, then you can run `modprobe fuse` and sshfs, and it stops complaining about FUSE.

Answer (score 1):

First you can try to install module from cache,

> apt-cache search fuse

if this doesn't work---
you can install fuse module with module-assistant,

> apt-get install module-assistant
>
> apt-get install fuse-source
>
> cd /usr/src
>
> m-a prepare
>
> m-a a-i fuse
>
> depmod -ae $(uname -r)

Now you can,

**modprobe fuse**

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package fuse-source`, I did `apt-get update`, do you know where is this located?